# How to reorganize table by group and/or add a new heading on an current heading?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, kableextra

I have a raw df with 4 columns: "Year", "Variable", "Frquency" and "%".

The years go from 2011 to 2022; and the variable correspond to an age, with subclassifications (e.g. 'age' can be < 5 years old, 5 to 10 years old and > 10 years old).
[Representation of whats my df looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRJRc.png)

The df is repeating the year 3 times for each classification of age. I would like to reorganize my df so that it shows each year one time as columns, and place the 3 classification of age as rows, so that in the end I can just use the KableExtra package to build a good looking table for my article.

[Model of table I'm aiming. The values are random...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlXRq.png)

I've tried to use `pivot_wider()` but the values of 'frequency' and '%' are separated into different columns by year, giving me two columns for year: frequency_2011; %_2011.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could paste frequency and % column in a single column and then pivot_wider transformation could be applied

Generate random data.frame (year, age, freq, perc)

```
df <- data.frame(expand.grid(year=seq(2011,2022),age=c("<5","5-10",">10")),freq=sample(seq(100,500),36),perc=sample(seq(1,100),36))
```

Paste freq and perc columns to generate freq.perc column (remove freq and perc column)

```
df2 <- df %>% transmute(year,age,freq.perc=paste0(freq," (",perc,"%)"))
```

Apply pivot_wider transformation

```
df3 <- df2 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = "year",values_from = "freq.perc")
```